# ERC20 token transfer without private Key

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, private-key

On my node there is an account, which I know the address and password, but do not know privateKey.
This account has tokens ERC20 and ETH for gas.
How can I transfer tokens to another wallet?

The usual translation I do so:

```
var privateKey = new EthJS.Buffer.Buffer(senderPrivateKey, 'hex')
var txParams = {
    nonce:    web3.toHex(count),
      gasPrice: gasPriceHex, 
    gasLimit: gasLimit,
      to: contractAddress, 
    value:    '0x00', 
    data:     contract.transferFrom.getData(senderAccount, recipientAccount, numberTokens),
      chainId: web3.toHex(1),
}
var tx=new EthJS.Tx(txParams);
tx.sign(privateKey),serializedTx=tx.serialize().toString('hex');
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x'+serializedTx, function(err, hash) {
    if (!err)
        console.log(hash);
    else
        console.log(err);
});
```

I can do web3.personal.unlockAccount, but how do I sign a transaction without private Key?

Comment: Not possible to sign without private key